# Preimage of open set. Problem with proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:X\to Y$ is continuous mapping between metric spaces. Then preimage of any open set is open.

Sorry if this topic is repeated but i have the following problem in my proof.

My proof: Let $V\subset Y$ be an open set. Taking $x\in f^{-1}(V)$ then $f(x)\in V$. Since $V$ is open then $\exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $N_{\varepsilon}(f(x))\subset V$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x$ then $\exists \delta>0$ such that for any $t\in X\cap N_{\delta}(x)$ we get $f(t)\in N_{\varepsilon}(f(x))\subset V$ or $t\in f^{-1}(V)$. Then we get $X\cap N_{\delta}(x)\subset f^{-1}(V).$ What the problem?

I get $X\cap N_{\delta}(x)\subset f^{-1}(V)$ but $X\cap N_{\delta}(x)$ may be not a ball.

Please help with this moment.

Comment: Your prove is fine and $X\cap N_{\delta}(x)= N_{\delta}(x)$ and, thus, an open ball. You don't have to intersect with the whole space.

Comment: @KoliG, Why $X\cap N_{\delta}(x)=N_{\delta}(x)$. Why our ball lies in whole space?

Comment: Usually the definition of a ball is $N_{\delta}(x)=\{y\in X: d(x,y)<\delta\}$, i.e., it is inherently in the definition.

Comment: @KoliG, Thanks a lot for your help! :)